# Selected value on a cloned item not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle is here, containing this code: http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/6/

```
<select id="aList">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>

<div id="newListContainer"></div>

$(function() {
    var value = 300;
    var clonedList = $('#aList').clone();    

    var listHtml = clonedList
        .removeAttr('id')
        .val(value)
        .wrap('<div/>')
        .parent()
        .html();

    $('#newListContainer').html(listHtml);       

    //$('#newListContainer>select').val(value);
});
```

I thought that my selected value of 300 would be maintained, but listHtml just contains a clone of the original list. I'm in a situation where it would be painful to try to re-find the object and set its value after it gets drawn (passing it to another external libraries function defers rendering till later, no complete callback unless I modify that library directly which I'm trying to avoid).

So am I doing something horribly wrong? Missing a quirk?

Clarification: I *need* to pass the HTML as a string, as the library that is using it is expecting a string.

Comment: jQuery clones the list with whatever you have selected - the problem here is that you don't have anything selected, so you're cloning a dropdown without a selected value ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/10/))

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: Note the `val` after the `clone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to make a round-trip to markup for this, and I suspect that's the problem, as jQuery's `val` sets the `selectedIndex` of the `select` element, which doesn't get serialized.

Just use the cloned element:

```
var wrappedList = clonedList
    .removeAttr('id')
    .val(value)
    .wrap('<div/>')
    .parent();
// Note: Not doing `.html()` at the end

// html(...) would empty the container and then add the HTML, so
// we empty the container and then append the wrapped, cloned list
$('#newListContainer').empty().append(wrappedList);
```

[Updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/12/)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/8/) link. You can't set `value` to the `select`, you must set `selected` attribute to item with `value=300`.

```
$(function() {
    var value = 300;
    var clonedList = $('#aList').clone();    
    clonedList.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr("selected", true);
    var listHtml = clonedList
        .removeAttr('id')
        //.val(value)
        .wrap('<div/>')
        .parent()
        .html();
    $('#newListContainer').html(listHtml);       

    //$('#newListContainer>select').val(value);
});
```

I have a mistake. @T.J. Crowder is right. jQuery can set `value` of select by `.val(value)` function. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/14/)

```
$(function() {
    var value = 300;
    var clonedList = $('#aList').clone();
    var holderCloned = clonedList.removeAttr('id').val(value).wrap('<div/>').parent();
    $('#newListContainer').empty().append(holderCloned);
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `val` does indeed work with `select` elements. The problem is the round-trip, which loses the `selectedIndex` of the `select`. This *also* works, because the `option` element's `selected` attribute is serialized. But again, there's just no reason for a round-trip to markup.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery clones the list with whatever you have selected - the problem here is that you don't have anything selected, so you're cloning a dropdown without a selected value ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/10/)).

For an updated version of that script, check this [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2T/13/).

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var value = 300;
    var clonedList = $('#aList').clone();
    clonedList.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    var listHtml = clonedList
        .removeAttr('id')
        .val(value)
        .wrap('<div/>')
        .parent()
        .html();

    $('#newListContainer').html(listHtml);       

    //$('#newListContainer>select').val(value);
});
```

Comment: *"the problem here is that you don't have anything selected"* But then the OP is **explicitly setting a value** on the cloned `select`, *after* cloning it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is the bit I'm referring to: "I thought that my selected value of 300 would be maintained" - but there is nothing selected

Comment: @ Zathrus: Perhaps "maintained" isn't the perfect word for the OP to have used, but the point is, he/she is *explicitly* setting the value on the cloned `select` (`val` does work with `select`s), and it's not set when the `select` is added.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there are so many points of view we could present here that we could expand this debate into a flame war :P but yeah, I get what you mean and hopefully, you get what I mean... what counts is that the OP has the answer now :)

Comment: @ Zathrus: I don't get what you're saying, actually, but it's not necessarily important that I do. :-) The OP has two different viable ways to go (don't go through markup, or go through markup but using `option.selected` rather than `select.selectedIndex`), so there we are!